Why dotnet keeps overriding my ports even when I specify them in the Dockerfile?
Question from the title.
I'm trying to create a live-reloading, in-container debugging setup with a sample project using .NET 8 SDK.
I'm exposing the ports and setting the environment variables in the dockerfile, according to the documentation.
However, I can't find, for the life of me, why on earth dotnet keeps overriding the ports I set up in the environment variables. Every time I run it, I keep getting the message Overriding HTTP_PORTS '5000' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://localhost:5017'
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my Dockerfile.debug file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY ./DockerTest.Domain/*.csproj ./DockerTest.Domain/
COPY ./DockerTest.Repository/*.csproj ./DockerTest.Repository/
COPY ./DockerTest.WebApi/*.csproj ./DockerTest.WebApi/

RUN dotnet restore

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--project" , "DockerTest.WebApi/DockerTest.WebApi.csproj", "--configuration", "Debug"]


I think it's telling you that it's using the ASPNETCORE_URLS variable and ignoring ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS. I'm confused as to why it binds to port 5017 though. Where does that come from?

@HansKilian I have no idea, but apparently, the dotnet watch command is ignoring whatever we have on the variables, and "obey" only what we pass via command line to him.

You can check launchSettings.json if there is any relevant port configuration, and whether there is any configuration that does not force binding to other ports.

Adding to above comments, I don't think you need ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS. try with just ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
